# Filter dataframe by removing duplicates from column containing list pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, unique

Dataframe columns contains string values in list. Dataframe needs to be transformed to have rows with unique lists in column 'Final'

I have dataframe as below,

```
    string1           string2           Final
1   [abc,ncx]       [qwe, rty]        [apple, mango]
2   [uio,pas,dfg]   [zxc,vbg,dfv]     [banana,grapes, apple]
3   [ncx,abc]       [rty,qwe]         [mango,apple]
4   [uio,pas,dfg]   [zxc,vbg,dfv]     [banana,grapes, apple]
5   [uio,dfg]        [zxc,dfv]        [banana, apple]
6   [ncx,abc]       [rty,qwe]         [mango,apple]
```

df['final'] column must drop duplicate lists and transform dataframe to contain unique list in 'final' column.

Desired output dataframe:

```
     string1           string2           Final
1   [abc,ncx]       [qwe, rty]        [apple, mango]
2   [uio,pas,dfg]   [zxc,vbg,dfv]     [banana,grapes, apple]
3   [ncx,abc]       [rty,qwe]         [mango,apple]
4   [uio,dfg]        [zxc,dfv]        [banana, apple]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert mask by `~` created by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), but because `list`s are not hashable first convert them to tuples and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['Final'].apply(tuple).duplicated()]
print (df)
         string1        string2                    Final
1      [abc,ncx]      [qwe,rty]           [apple, mango]
2  [uio,pas,dfg]  [zxc,vbg,dfv]  [banana, grapes, apple]
3      [ncx,abc]      [rty,qwe]           [mango, apple]
5      [uio,dfg]      [zxc,dfv]          [banana, apple]
```

If `apple, mango` should be duplicate with `mango, apple` (order is not important) change `tuple` to `frozenset`:

```
df = df[~df['Final'].apply(frozenset).duplicated()]
print (df)
         string1        string2                    Final
1      [abc,ncx]      [qwe,rty]           [apple, mango]
2  [uio,pas,dfg]  [zxc,vbg,dfv]  [banana, grapes, apple]
5      [uio,dfg]      [zxc,dfv]          [banana, apple]
```

Comment: I guess it matters if list order is important.  maybe `apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))` or the like?

Comment: @anon01 - I think frozenset should be used here, answer was edited.

Comment: ah yeah, makes sense!

Comment: @anon01@jezrael order is important. First code with tuple works fine. Thank you